# IOs Padding TextField de MaterialComponents.MaterialTextFields

Tags: swift

Actualmente tengo un `TextField`  (`MaterialComponents.MaterialTextFields`) con un fondo como la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al escribir se ve de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es meterle un padding o relleno para que no quede tan pegado a la izquierda ,

Mi caja es de tipo textField Materials

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: TextField!



func setupStyles(){
    self.txtPassword.textColor =  Utils.Color.COLOR_A0856A
    self.txtPassword.dividerNormalColor =  Utils.Color.COLOR_A0856A
    self.txtPassword.dividerActiveColor =  Utils.Color.COLOR_A0856A
    self.txtPassword.attributedPlaceholder =
        NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("strTxtPassword",comment:""), attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor(red:0.74, green:0.78, blue:0.83, alpha:1.0)])
    }
```

Utilizo Swift 4

Con TextField y material me refiero a esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

utlizando la solucion de Shadros

```
 self.strPhoneTxt.setLeftPaddingPoints(5)
```

me genera :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si cambio a
`self.strPhoneTxt.setLeftPaddingPoints(2)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin exito

Comment: Te refieres a MaterialComponents.MaterialTextFields ? @brunososafasttag

Comment: @Elenasys edite la pregunta con una imagen ilustrativa  estoy recien empezando me imagino que si es eso que dices Jorge / Elena? cambiaste de nombre

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para hacer un padding te adjunto una extensión del TextField y su forma de usarla:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UITextField {
    func setLeftPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat){
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))
        self.leftView = paddingView
        self.leftViewMode = .always
    }
    func setRightPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat) {
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))
        self.rightView = paddingView
        self.rightViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

Y para usarla:

```
txtPassword.setLeftPaddingPoints(25)
```

Espero que sea lo que buscas.

Comment: SI la respuesta te ha sido de utilidad márcala como válida para ayudar a la comunidad.

Comment: en cuanto lo pruebe te la marco para respuesta  , igual dedo para arriba

Comment: por mas que ponga 5 o 25 el relleno es el mismo , este efecto no es el deseado

Comment: El código lo probé antes de publicarlo, y hace un padding a derecha o izquierda, según se elija y aplica los pixels indicados. Prueba a poner la caja de texto un borde negro sólido para que veas lo que ocupa y veras como el padding cambia según el valor que introduzcas

Comment: edite la pregunta @Shadros

Comment: ¿Has creado una clase personalizada para la caja de texto? Si es eso el código que te he pasado lo has de poner dentro de tu class TextField

Comment: no no tengo ninguna clase personalizada

Answer (score 3):

Puedes probar esto, por ejemplo:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField! {
    didSet {
        nameTextField.layer.cornerRadius =  5
        nameTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        nameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        let leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 2.0))
        nameTextField.leftView = leftView
        nameTextField.leftViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

Con el cual se obtiene el siguiente resultado:

[image: left padding]

Puede usar también una función en lugar de configurarla `didSet` y algo así como:

```
func addPaddingAndBorder(to textfield: UITextField) {
    textfield.layer.cornerRadius =  5
    textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    textfield.layer.borderWidth = 1
    let leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 2.0))
    textfield.leftView = leftView
    textfield.leftViewMode = .always
}
```

y luego llamas eso, `viewDidLoadpor` ejemplo, así:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addPaddingAndBorder(to: nameTextField)
}
```

---

**Otra Manera es:**

Una forma personalizada de agregar relleno a lado: `"left"`, `"right"` o `"both"` en `UITextField`.

**Paso 1: agregue esta extensión UITextfield**

```
extension UITextField {

    enum PaddingSide {
        case left(CGFloat)
        case right(CGFloat)
        case both(CGFloat)
    }

    func addPadding(_ padding: PaddingSide) {

        self.leftViewMode = .always
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true


        switch padding {

        case .left(let spacing):
            let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: spacing, height: self.frame.height))
            self.leftView = paddingView
            self.rightViewMode = .always

        case .right(let spacing):
            let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: spacing, height: self.frame.height))
            self.rightView = paddingView
            self.rightViewMode = .always

        case .both(let spacing):
            let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: spacing, height: self.frame.height))
            // left
            self.leftView = paddingView
            self.leftViewMode = .always
            // right
            self.rightView = paddingView
            self.rightViewMode = .always
        }
    }        
}
```

**Paso 2: Cómo usar**

```
// 1.  Para agregar relleno izquierdo
yourTextFieldName.addPadding(.left(20)) 

// 2.  Para agregar relleno Derecho
yourTextFieldName.addPadding(.right(20))

// 3. Para agregar relleno izquierdo y derecho (ambos)
yourTextFieldName.addPadding(.both(20))
```

> Fuente SO: [How do you create textfield padding in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47581777/8933039)

Comment: Como dije arriba esto funciona , con la clase de UITextField , pero no con la clase TextField Tipo Materials  , arriba deje la configuracion que utilizo

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag, comprendo, lamento no poder brindarle una mejor solución